# How to add a new "top" row to a table in jquery without deleting the other rows

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

First off - I did look at [How to replace innerHTML of a div using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309452/how-to-replace-innerhtml-of-a-div-using-jquery) and that's great if I want to replace the fill tag `<tr>` in this case.

I'm trying to make a dynamic table that is loading off of an API for crypto-mining. Whenever there are new blocks hit, I want to add them to the top of the table and delete any over 100 (Only 100 `<tr>` max).

Right now, what I'm doing is:

```
document.getElementById('blockList').innerHTML += "<tr><td>" ...
```

This adds rows to the top of:

```
<table class="table1">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Time (Local)</th>
            <th class='collapsableHeader' onclick='collapseTable()'>Hash</th>
            <th>Height</th>
            <th>Effort</th>
            <th>Found By</th>
            <th>Pool/Solo</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="blockList"></tbody>
</table>
```

The problem with the way I'm doing it now is that it clears the entire table:

```
document.getElementById("blockList").innerHTML = "";
```

...this causes a bit of flashing, or "twitching" as I prefer to call it, while the data reloads everytime my `setInterval()` is called (about every 10 seconds).

My first hope is that jQuery will minimize or remove the flashing. Here's where I get hung up - the link above is to replace the tag with new information with either:

```
$("#blockList").html("STUFF TO REPLACE EXISTING STUFF");
//or
$("#blockList").text("STUFF TO REPLACE EXISTING STUFF");
```

`text()` won't work in my case because I'm using the `innerHTML +=` to add the tags as well...

```
document.getElementById('blockList').innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + displayBlocks[i]["timestamp"] + "</td><td class='collapsable'>" + displayBlocks[i]["hash"] + "</td><td class='collapsablePlaceholders'>|</td><td>" + displayBlocks[i]["height"] + "</td><td style='color:" + displayBlocks[i]["luckColor"] + "'>" + displayBlocks[i]["luck"] + "</td><td>" + displayBlocks[i]["worker"] + "</td><td>" + displayBlocks[i]["ps"] + "</td><td>" + displayBlocks[i]["status"] + "</td></tr>";
```

If this is possible, then removing the rows > 100 will be easy (I hope).

So - all this to say:

> Is it possible to ADD information to an `id`/`tag` in jQuery without deleting all of the existing data in it. Basically the equivalent to `.innerHTML +=` specifically the `+=` part.

Comment: `$('#blocklist').prepend(yourNewElements)`, see: [`prepend()`](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some examples on how to add to top, add to bottom, remove from top and remove from bottom using JQ

```js
let n = 0
$('button').click(function() {
  n++
  let fakerow = `<tr><td>${n}</td><td>12:34</td><td>123123123</td><td>10</td><td>??</td><td>Fred</td><td>Solo</td><td>available</td></tr>`;

  let action = $(this).data('action');
  if (action == 'add-top') {
    $('#blockList').prepend($(fakerow))
  } else if (action == 'add-bottom') {
    $('#blockList').append($(fakerow))
  } else if (action == 'remove-top') {
    $('#blockList tr').first().remove()
  } else if (action == 'remove-bottom') {
    $('#blockList tr').last().remove()

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table1">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Time (Local)</th>
      <th class='collapsableHeader' onclick='collapseTable()'>Hash</th>
      <th>Height</th>
      <th>Effort</th>
      <th>Found By</th>
      <th>Pool/Solo</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="blockList"></tbody>
</table>
<hr>

<button data-action='add-top'>Add row to top</button>
<button data-action='add-bottom'>Add row to end</button>
<hr>
<button data-action='remove-top'>Remove row from top</button>
<button data-action='remove-bottom'>Remove row from end</button>
```

Comment: I realise you're more than able to have done this yourself, *and* jQuery was specified, but I couldn't resist a plain JavaScript alternative: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/58zng3tf/1/) (and an over-complicated [first-draft](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/58zng3tf/), of course).

Comment: @DavidThomas I appreciate the follow-through. The only problem with that is the #s keep going where they left off instead of going to the lowest unused integer :)

Comment: @jpgerb: I think that’s intentional, so that you can see which element was removed, and mostly because otherwise each row is identical.